# Windows Phone: AppBar icons appearing differently on the device

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm mocking up an app in Expression Blend. The app bar looks fine in Blend, but when I launch the emulator the icon doesn't display properly.

The XAML for the app bar:

```
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="FavoritesBar" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
      <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/assets/appbar.favs.rest.png" Text="favorites"/>
  </shell:ApplicationBar>
```

Below left is the way it is rendered in Expression Blend. Below right is the way it appears in the emulator.

[image: showing the problem: expression blend on left, wp7 emulator on right]

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have marked the appbar.favs.rest.png as Content in Properties->Build Action.

Comment: In VS 2010, I'm not seeing Properties->Build Action. I see "Build" and "Build Events", however. In Blend, I just see two .xml files and a .cs file.

Comment: Oh, wait, different Properties.